# Sharing cookies between many pages?

Tags: html, cookies

Is it possible to use cookies set by one page (say page1.html) by another page (say page2.html) in the same web site?

Answer (score 4):

As I recall, it depends on what path you give for the cookie.  If you write to a path and then request from that path inside the same domain you will have access to that cookie value.

from a server side perspective (courtesy of wikipedia)

Set-Cookie: name=newvalue; expires=date; path=/; domain=.example.org

Often path is set to the pages relative path so that vars are retained for just that page, maybe for summary/detail choice on that page.  For other cookies you set the path to / so you can access a common value like rowsPerPage or something similar thats site wide.

heres a wikipedia link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie

Answer (score 1):

Cookie is shared by default if you correctly specify the domain and the path.

Answer (score 0):

The cookie is stored in the client browser for the current domain

Read more about it here : [link text](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie)